# Struggling with the deployment of whenever cron jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cron, capistrano, whenever

I have a Rails 4 application deployed with Capistrano 3.
Lately I tried adding some cron jobs using Whenever Gem.

The problem is basically when I deploy- none of the     `schedule.rb` jobs aren't exists. Also, I don't see any of the log files generated in the log path-    `...path/to/app/shared/log/`

Here's my configuration:
**Gemfile:**

```
# Use whenever to schedule jobs using Cron
gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

**Capfile:** (added the appropriate require based on whenever docs)

```
require 'whenever/capistrano'
```

**deploy.rb:**

```
### See great guid on this in http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2014/01/deploying-rails-apps-to-a-vps-with-capistrano-v3/ ###

# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.2.1'

# Set local variables:
application = 'eng_performance'
home = '/home/deploy'


set :application, application
set :repo_url, "git@gitlab.com:danklei/#{application}.git"
set :branch, 'SmartAdmin1_4_1'

# Set the server deploy path of the application
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"

# Set linked-files in order to share secret files without deploying them to the DB.
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/jenkinsCredentials.yml}

# Set directories we want symlinking to share
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

# Set what specs should run before deployment is allowed to continue (see lib/capistrano/tasks/run_tests)
set :tests, []

# Set which config files should be copied by deploy:setup_config
# see documentation in lib/capistrano/tasks/setup_config.cap
# for details of operations
set(:config_files, %w(
  database.example.yml
  jenkinsCredentials.example.yml
))

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    # on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
    on roles(:web), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Restart Phusion Passenger
      info 'restarting Phusion Passenger service'
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')

    end
  end

  desc "Update application's crontab entries using Whenever"
  task :update_crontab do
    setup_whenever_task do |host|
      roles = host.roles_array.join(",")
      [fetch(:whenever_update_flags),  "--roles=#{roles}"]
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

  after :clear_cache, :update_crontab

end

after :deploy, "app_setup:create_tests_log_symlink"
```

**schedule.rb:**

```
# Use this file to easily define all of your cron jobs.
#
# It's helpful, but not entirely necessary to understand cron before proceeding.
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

set :output, {:error => "#{path}/log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "#{path}/log/cron_log.log"}

every 1.minute do
    command "date"     <-- this is just a sanity job to make sure something started working

end

every 1.day, at: "8:42" do
    command "echo updating golden_results db relation with rake task: update_golden_results"
    rake "golden:update_golden_results[false,true]"
end

every :reboot, :roles => [:web] do
    rake "golden:refresh_golden_comparison"
end

every 1.day, at: "4am", :roles => [:web] do
    command "echo refreshing rails cache with rake task: golden:refresh_golden_comparison"
    rake "golden:refresh_golden_comparison"
end

every 1.week, at: "4am", :roles => [:web] do
    command "echo updating golden_results db relation with rake task: update_golden_results"
    rake "golden:update_golden_results[false,false]"
end
```

**note:** I've added the whenever provided     `whenever.rake` file into    `/app/lib/capistrano/tasks/whenever.rake` and also copied the    `:update_crontab` task into my     `deploy.rb` file as I didn't know what would be the best practice of using that.

I'd appreciate any help...
Thanks!

Comment: did you add the environment in your deploy.rb file like this `set :whenever_environment, defer { stage #define either production or staging whichever you are using here }`

Comment: @anusha, got it and added it.
Indeed, I can see now that the log files added into my    `/log` directory.
But I guess I miss something. when I ran `"cap production deploy"` the   `every :reboot...` task should have worked. Nothing happened though..

Also, can you recommend where to place the     `:update_crontab` task?
Thanks!

Comment: then you can call the `:update_crontab` task before deploy   `before :deploy, :update_crontab` check for logs once

Comment: Which     `:update_crontab` are you suggest using? The one I defined inside the    `deploy.rb` file of the one provided with     `whenever.rake` that I added completely into     `/app/lib/capistrano/tasks/whenever.rake`.

BTW - I ended up changing     `set :whenever_roles,->{ :web }` and not the environment as the default roles are     `:db` alone.
Feel free to add an answer so that I will mark as the correct one if everything checks out ok.

Comment: did it worked for you

Comment: the   `:update_crontab` works. It actually triggers the "sanity job" (printing date every minute), but it doesn't kicking the   `:reboot` when the server reboots after issuing     `cap production deploy`.

Comment: I have added the answer please accept if it worked for you

Comment: Thanks, I've just read in the [whenever readme](https://github.com/javan/whenever#capistrano-integration) that the      `set :whenever_environment, defer { stage }` is capistrano v2. Are you sure this applies to capistrano v3 as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
if you don't specify this earlier please add this to your **deploy.rb** file

```
set :whenever_environment, defer { stage #define either production or staging whichever you are using here }
```

and also

**deploy.rb**

```
desc "Update application's crontab entries using Whenever"
  task :update_crontab do
   on roles(:web, :db, :app), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
    setup_whenever_task do |host|
      roles = host.roles_array.join(",")
      [fetch(:whenever_update_flags),  "--roles=#{roles}"]
    end
  end

   before :deploy, :update_crontab
```

**Update:**

Off course we can but the sysntax is different as like this

```
set :whenever_identifier, ->{ "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}" }
```

it was in whenever github link also please check once https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: I was mistaken to think that    `:reboot` refer to the application (rails/passenger) service restart, where in fact it is related to the actual machine reboot.